# How do I view my subscribers/contacts who belong to a specific group?

Tags: mailchimp

I am *very* new to `mailchimp` but I have managed to upload my subscriber email list. I have also created various groups based on my subscribers' interests and have added the subscribers to these various groups. But I have been spending quite a bit of time trying to figure out how I might filter my contacts based on what group they are in. For example, I might just want to view only contacts who are in group "Abc" belonging to category "Xyz". But I cannot figure out how to do that.

For what it's worth, the way I added contacts to a group was to first create a `bulk tag contacts` operation corresponding to that group and then copying and pasting the email addresses of the contacts I wanted to add to the group. Having tagged these contacts, I then filtered the contacts on that tag, selected all the filtered contacts and then added these contacts to the group. Of course, I can filter the contents of the group just by filtering on the tag of the same name. But when new people subscribe and become members of a group, they will not automatically get tagged (and I don't want to get involved with webhooks). So I would like to get rid of these tags that have served their purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click on the `Audience` menu item.
2. Click on `Manage Audience Contacts` drop down. From the drop down list, select `Manage contacts`.
3. Click on the `View Groups` link.
4. Click on the `View Groups` button for the category you are interested in.
5. The category will expand to show links for all the groups within the category. If you click one of those links, just those contacts within the group will be displayed.